# Editing Jekyll themes for use with Github Pages

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I just started working with Github pages and have no prior experience with Jekyll.

I'm trying to edit a github-pages theme to suit my needs. So I cloned it and started editing the `default.html` file in _layouts. But when I run `bundle exec jekyll serve` it still generates the original theme's `default.html`. I even pushed it to the remote and my user website generates the original theme.

The github-pages theme I'm working on is called midnight. And i'm trying to get rid of the nav

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Are you using the gem 'github-pages' when building the website locally? And would it be possible to share a link to the repo or include some snippets of code?